# Table column stick to top, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to hear if you could stick your content of column one to the top no matter of how much text-lines there is in the other column.

Right now I have it like this:

[image]

but I want to have the posters info to stick to the top, like this:

[image]

so no matter how much text there is in the "hey" column, the poster-info always stick in the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align: top` to the `td` element. This will set the alignment of the text in all the data cells to the top.

Comment: Thanks alot. I've been searching all over the internet.